# Permutation of numbers and function

Tags: functions, permutations

Let $N(x)$ denote the number of terminating zeroes of the number x. If A,B,C is a permutation of the numbers $211^{19}+9$, $9^{101}-9$, and $19^{111}-9$ such that $N(A)<N(B)<N(C)$, determine the ordered triple $(A,B,C)$.

Comment: Modular exponentiation is your friend. Work modulo $10$, if the result is $0$, do it again.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to ask. Plus does "permutation" mean the arrangement of the three numbers?

Comment: Yes, they just mean you have to sort them by the number of terminated zeroes.

Comment: The hint by orion works sufficiently well because the $N()$ values happe to be $1,2,3$.

Comment: So there will be six different sets

Comment: Btw, what is modular exponentiation

Comment: I haven't learned anything about compsci, or cryptography

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : $211^{19}=(1+210)^{19}=1+ \binom{19}{1}210+\binom{19}{2}210^2...$

Google Binomial Theorem if u didn't get that step.

Last Digit : $1$ // All other terms have at least one zero at end

Second Last : $9$ // see second term. last is 0. second last is 9 as u multiply 19 by 210.                            all other terms have at least 2 zeros at end.

Third Last : $9+1$=$0$ //third last in second term is 9(19*210) and we also have to look for third term as it had only 2 zeroes and we want third last digit. Rest terms have more than three zeroes

You need not compute full 2nd and 3rd terms only sufficient last digits.

You should stop here as when you add 9 that will become 1.

Can you proceed for other numbers?

Comment: Is it possible that you could explain your works in simpler terms, starting off with the way you break 211^19 down into those polynomials.

Comment: will edit­­­­­­

Comment: Is the problem asking the terminating zeroes for all three functions?

Comment: @user139024 yes it is

Answer (score 0):

$$211^{19}+9=1^{19}+9=0\mod 10$$
Try again:
$$211^{19}+9=11^{19}+9=11\cdot (11^2)^{9}+9=11\cdot 21^{9}+9=(11\cdot 21)(21^2)^4+9=31\cdot 41^4+9=31\cdot 81^2+9=31\cdot 61+9=0\mod 100$$

Here, I repeatedly squared, reduced modulo $100$ before squaring again in order to never work with too big numbers.

So it has at least 2 zeroes. Continue until you get nonzero. It's not the fastest solution, but in this situation it works.

Comment: The problem is just asking which number has the most terminating zeroes?

Comment: Yes, just sort.